# Show list after slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html-lists, toggle

I am newbie to jQuery and I have problem regarding my project.

I have `li` elements created by php and with each `li` element I get `div` layout showing some data.

I would like to be able to click to title located in `li` and be able to show `div` layout and hide everything else, but when I click again on title it hides layout `div` and show all of list again.

Here is structure:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="date">date</div>
    <a href="#" class="click">Title dynamically 1</a>
    <div id="location">location</div>
    <div class="layout">Data dynamically 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="date">date</div>
    <a href="#" class="click">Title dynamically 2</a>
    <div id="location">location</div>
    <div class="layout">Data dynamically 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery code:

```
  $('li a').click(function () {
          $('li a').next('.layout').slideToggle(600);
               $('li a').not(this).slideToggle(600);
```

With this code it only hides title and doesn't show layout

I have tried lot of combinations but no luck, can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Various problems in your code:

1. Your Javascript isn't even balanced and throw errors when executed.
2. `$('li a')` matches all such elements. That said, you are going to toggle slide for everything when clicking a link
3. You design is also a bit flawed - if I understand correctly. You want to hide everything, including the link itself, when clicking on the link. Obviously, you are not going to show the link again if the very link itself is hidden...
4. You are not using [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) right, which only get the next element no matter what.
5. You want to show the `.layout` on click, but it is already shown? I bet you forgot to put `display: none` for `.layout` elements.

I believe this is what you want. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AP9kv/)

CSS

```
.layout {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('li a').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().not('a').slideToggle(600);
});
```

1. `$(this)` indicates the element clicked, converted to a jQuery object
2. [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) get all siblings of the element
3. [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) removes the `a` element from the just retrieved siblings list so that the link is not hidden
4. Finally, actually call slideToggle. jQuery is clever enough to hide everything which was shown (`everything else`) and show everything which was hidden (`.layout`).

Additionally, please do not have multiple elements having the same `id` in the same page. Use `class` if those `id`s can duplicate. That said, replace

```
<div id="date">date</div>
<div id="location">location</div>
```

to

```
<div class="date">date</div>
<div class="location">location</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/eUzk8/

*Use css class instead of id for multiple lists.

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="date">date</div>
        <a href="#" class="title">Title dynamically 1</a>
        <div class="location">location</div>
        <div class="layout">Data dynamically 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="date">date</div>
        <a href="#" class="title">Title dynamically 2</a>
        <div class="location">location</div>
        <div class="layout">Data dynamically 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## JQUERY

```
$('.title').click(function () { 
    var current = $(this).parent('li').children('.layout').css('display');
    if(current == 'none'){
        $(this).parent('li').children('.layout').slideDown(600);
        $(this).parent('li').children('.date, .location').not(this).hide();
    }
    if(current == 'block'){
        $(this).parent('li').children('.layout').slideUp(600);
        $(this).parent('li').children('.date, .location').not(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello guys, i have found solution for my problem :) Here is my code - thank you very much for tips http://jsfiddle.net/onebeat/cEzbx/